# Regex to capture email id which start just after some special string

Tags: regex

I have many thunderbird exported file. I need to collect the **email id** from each file. All emails are bounced email id, thats why we need to remove them from our system.

The String

```
Reporting-MTA: dsn; a27-19.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822; mrinalkantighosh005@gmail.com

Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
```

Every email id start with Final-Recipient: rfc822; mrinalkantighosh005@gmail.com

So the format is `Final-Recipient: rfc822; EMAIL_ID_HERE`

Can you guys please let me know the regex to extract the email id.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
I am able to extract all the email ids. This regex is selecting all email ids:-

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]‌​+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x‌​0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\‌​x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\‌​[\x01-\x09\x0b\x‌​0c\x0e-\x7f])")@(?:(‌​?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9‌​-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-‌​z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a‌​-z0-9])?|[(?:(?:‌​25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|‌​[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.)‌​{3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]‌​[0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9‌​]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9‌​]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\‌​x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5‌​a\x53-\x7f]|\[\x‌​01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-‌​\x7f])+)])
```

But i just need to capture email id which start just after the "Final-Recipient: rfc822;" string.

Comment: **Clarify you question**

Comment: Hi k-five, We have a long string with multiple email ids. But we just want to extract the email id which start just after the "Final-Recipient: rfc822;" string.

Comment: This regex is extracting all the email ids in the string: (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])

Comment: @ShariqueAnwer Add that to the question and explain what the issue is with it.

Comment: What flavor of regex do you use? `perl` or `php` or `js` or ... since for math **just after something** you can use **look-behind** assertion

Comment: @ShariqueAnwer [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/3Xv7se/1)

Comment: Yes it Works!! Thank you so much @k-five

Comment: @ShariqueAnwer, **really???** that is not an appropriate pattern for matching `email` I just want you to see the **look-behind** assertion. no problem :)

Comment: @k-five Really it works. My problem is solved. In case if you want to post answer, you can. Thanks.

Comment: If the TLD is not `com` that won't work..and/or might return incorrect results. e.g. `chris_commercial@np.org`

Comment: I can use the same regex with changed tld.

Comment: @ShariqueAnwer You're going to list every `tld`? Also if anything else is on that line with one of the other TLDs you'll get a false result. Good luck, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains.

Comment: Oh yes, I just face this problem. Do you have any solution? I am really thankful to you.

Comment: @ShariqueAnwer You need to thoroughly test "answers" before accepting. I wouldn't consider what've selected as an answer. Is the email address always at the end of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Works perfectly:-

```
(?(?<=Final-Recipient: rfc822;).[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Answer (score 1):

For matching just something after you want you can use **look-behind** assertion. Since this assertion has `zero-length` and does not matching anything, you can put your patten after your look-behind assertion. Something like this:

## [(?<=Final-Recipient: ).*com](https://regex101.com/r/3Xv7se/1)

> NOTE
> that is not an appropriate pattern for matching email I just
> want you to see the look-behind assertion

Comment: Good luck catching `Final-Recipient: rfc822; mrinalkantighosh005@hotmail.co.uk`

Comment: @ThomasAyoub **Of course this a stupid pattern but that person just needed a `look-behind assertion` nothing else. I said two times and asked and he/she said that the problem was solved**